# how to find files with cygwin

Tags: cygwin, find

We like to search many directories in a Windows environment with cygwin.
We tried find . -name *.txt -print

but it complains the -print predicate.
What is the correct command then ?

We only want matched files printed to console.

Thanks all

Answer (score 4):

It is complaining because you have not quoted the `*.txt` so the shell is expanding the pattern instead of passing it to `find`. In other words, let's say you are in a directory that contains these files:

```
 foo.txt bar.txt baz.txt
```

When you say `find . -name *txt -print` the wildcard (`*`) is expanded by the shell (bash probably) so what is passed to f`find`is actually:

```
find . -name foo.txt bar.txt baz.txt -print
```

That's too many arguments and `find` complains. To get what you want, you need to quote the pattern you a re searching for (you also don't need the `-print` for what you are doing):

```
 find . -name "*txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Could not get `find` to work on Cygwin either. `File not found` error all the time.
The problem was Windows has its own version:

```
$ which find
/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/find
```

I solved it by typing /usr/bin/find everywhere but I suppose you could change path priorities or rename Windows' find.exe